# Flutter Flexible does not take entire space

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, chat, flutter-layout

I have this chat item similar to what you see on WhatsApp.

This is what I have so far.

```dart
ListView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Dismissible(
              key: Key(""),
              background: Container(color: Colors.grey[200]),
              direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
              child: InkWell(
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 12, 0),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                        radius: 30,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "John Doe",
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Lorem ipsum, or something idk about this",
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[800]
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
//                                      Padding(
//                                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
//                                        child: Text(
//                                          "John Doe",
//                                          maxLines: 1,
//                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
//                                          style: TextStyle(
//                                            fontSize: 16,
//                                          ),
//                                        ),
//                                      ),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "12:02",
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      height: 1,
                      indent: 90,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

The list view is part of the body of a scaffold.

Currently only the middle part of this is the issue. And by issue I mean it is not flexing all the way. The right hand side where it says 12:02 should only expand if it has to otherwise minimum size should be applied. I am extremely lost.

Thanks for any help!

I have added this image to show what it looks like so far.

[image: image example]

Comment: you want Lorem text to drawn on single line?

Comment: No. I want the entire container for it to expand the remaining space. So that the 2 lines make most use of it. Same way as shown on telegram. You can see here what I mean (https://telegram.org/file/811140089/1a1a/El2hG5wVR34.46491/7dc806e6a17f4bf077)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Expanded` Widget

```
ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Dismissible(
            key: Key(""),
            background: Container(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
            child: InkWell(
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              onTap: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 12, 0),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                      radius: 30,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "John Doe",
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Lorem ipsum, or something idk about this",
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                            Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                    children: [
//                                      Padding(
//                                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
//                                        child: Text(
//                                          "John Doe",
//                                          maxLines: 1,
//                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
//                                          style: TextStyle(
//                                            fontSize: 16,
//                                          ),
//                                        ),
//                                      ),

                                      Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "12:02",
                                          maxLines: 2,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey[800],
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ),
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    height: 1,
                    indent: 90,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: this is the exact behavior which screenshot have

Comment: which screenshot. the one I provided in this post or the one in the comments. if you mean the one I provided in the post then it should not be like that. the centre part should stretch all its remaining space. so far it is still same with this code you provided. but thank you

Comment: comment section it was

Comment: yes. I tried it again just now. it is the same. as before. I am not sure why it is not expanding

Comment: what you really want to expand?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there really isn't a good none hacky solution. It seems to work quite well with positions and a stack.

Here is the code.

```
Dismissible(
        key: Key(""),
        background: Container(color: Colors.grey[200]),
        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
        child: InkWell(
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 12),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Text(
                            "Mon",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.grey[600]
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 4, 8, 4),
                              child: Text(
                                "123",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 12, 0),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                      radius: 30,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "John Doe",
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Lorem ipsumahskhdk ashkda ",
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 60,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                height: 1,
                indent: 90,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```